# Development of standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a cloud of (x,y) variables which show two tendencies.

1. They appear linear.
2. As x increases, the y values become more spread out.

Using linear regression, I can plot a nice line through them but how can I get an indication of how the standard deviation of the points develops?

Comment: Does the spread seem to increase linearly or in some other way? Does it seem as if it would it be smallest at x=0 or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could simply be a case of heteroskedastic errors. Heteroskedastic errors simply means that the variance of your error term is non-constant. 
Using a linear regression to fit your points you would get a specification of the sort:

$$y_i=\beta x_i + \upsilon_i$$

where $$  V(\upsilon_i | x_i) = \sigma^2 h^2_i $$

Then, depending on your variables, you can place some assumptions on your function $h$.